# Mule request-reply consuming all the messages in the JMS reply queue

Tags: mule

In Mule Request-Reply pattern, JMS inbound endpoint is consuming all the messages in the queue. 
how can i avoid this behavior of mule.
here is my flow

```
<request-reply timeout="100000">
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="request"
            connector-ref="Active_MQ" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="JMS- REQUEST" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="false" >
            <message-properties-transformer>
                <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="reply"
            connector-ref="Active_MQ" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="JMS-REPLY"/ >
```

All the messages in 'reply' queue is consumed irrespective of Correlation Id.
Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a selector on the JMS inbound endpoint:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="reply"
        connector-ref="Active_MQ" exchange-pattern="one-way"
        doc:name="JMS-REPLY"/ >
    <jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID=#[message.correlationId]"/>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: Also i see that JMS consumer is created at mule startup.

Comment: OK so this sucks then :( The last idea I have is to try if a `requester` from https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester could be used in lieu of the `jms:inbound-endpoint`. That way, the MEL expression would be evaluated each time it's called. If that doesn't work then the answer is no: the `request-reply` consumes everything from the reply queue.