# How to Listen data from particular Correlation Id and Queue in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with mule and i am using JMS inbound to listen particular queue. I want to configure my JMS in such a way that if i am pushing data from Active MQ with particular correlation id and that correlation id is already configured in Mule JMS Inbound. It will listen and poll only that. Please share some JMS XML configuration for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter called `jms:selector` in JMS inbound to select a particular type of message based on it's properties

Now, as you said you are pushing a message from ActiveMQ with a particular corelation id so, you can select the message to consume in your Mule based on that particular corelation id as follows :-

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="reply"
        connector-ref="Active_MQ" exchange-pattern="one-way"
        doc:name="JMS-REPLY"/ >
    <jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID='your corelation id'"/>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

You can see, the example here :- [Mule request-reply consuming all the messages in the JMS reply queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129215/mule-request-reply-consuming-all-the-messages-in-the-jms-reply-queue)

But, again, I would suggest you not to filter a message based corelation id, if that corelation id is not defined in your message you are pushing or you are not setting as static id, it may unable to consume if the corelation id differs.

So, rather I would suggest you to filter the message based on message priority,which is the best way to filter JMS messages.

Here is how, you can set a message priority in Mule flow itself on JMS messages and consume it based on that priority property :-
[Mule: JMS reply queue consumes all the messages. I want to process messages that coming to reply queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394528/mule-jms-reply-queue-consumes-all-the-messages-i-want-to-process-messages-that)